# Brew installation - not a valid reference error

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I am trying to install homebrew on macos m1 chip, with the one-line command but keep running into the following error. Could someone please help me to fix this? Thank you.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R miththinda:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at a0ae4a7a0 Merge pull request #12658 from sjackman/sj/linkage-checker
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 13):

Removing the directory and trying to reinstall worked for me.

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Comment: This solution was saved me. Thankz

Answer (score 3):

Please run the following commands in your terminal:

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)  # because you can't `brew untap homebrew/core`
brew tap homebrew/core
```

You can check the details of the issue [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10368).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on ***Mac***, I uninstalled it first by typing the command below and I installed Xcode, it worked for me after running the ***install*** command again.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I first installed it onto my Linux system using the command recommended on the homebrew install page:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

but it seem to take a long time, and "hung" showing the output:

```
Resolving deltas: 100% (793706/793706), done.
```

for quite a while. I was impatient and killed the process then, and tried the install again.  That is when I got the error reported by the OP. The fix was to uninstall the partially installed homebrew, and install again:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```